# Dot Net Nuke - How to Register a User Control in Version 5

Tags: dotnetnuke

Trying to follow internet guides I've found, but there seems to be a difference in the way the latest version works.

I am trying to register a user control as instructed at the link below, but I dont't see the module definitions options that would allow me to complete the set up of a module (useing a test user control I have created).

Screen as I see it is attached

Can any one point me in the right direction?

http://adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/DNN_ShowMeThePages/Super_Simple2.htm[alt text http://bombdefused.com/dnn.png](http://bombdefused.com/dnn.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are in layout mode where you cannot see page content, click on edit radio button at top right corner.